# Javascript date backward

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compute the date of the day before using:

```
var da = new Date('2016-11-25');
nda = new Date(da-86400000);
```

It seems to work well when printed out using:

```
document.write(nda);
```

The output is:

Thu Nov 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (WET)

which is correct, but when I do:

```
document.write(nda.getFullYear()+"-"+nda.getMonth()+"-"+nda.getDay());
```

I get a wrong output:

2016-10-4

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using: `var d = new Date();
 d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);`?

Comment: `getMonth()` returns a number between 0 and 11, being 0 January, so... +1 ;)

Comment: `getMonth()` returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year) and `getDay()` returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday - See MDN Documentation on [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) and [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: @ScottMarcus the reason is... it gives the same problem

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `nda.getMonth() + 1`.
Months start from 0 so in order to get the right number of the month you must add 1.

Also you need to use `getDate()` instead of `getDay()`. getDay will give you the day of the week, while getDate will give you the day of the month.

The end result would be:

```
nda.getFullYear() + "-" + (nda.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + nda.getDate()
```

Comment: That addresses half of the problem, the other half is the use of `getDay()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var da = new Date('2016-11-25');
nda = new Date(da-86400000);

document.write((nda.getFullYear())+
               "-"+(nda.getMonth()+1)+
               "-"+(nda.getDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns the index of the month, which is 0-indexed (So 0 is January, and 11 is December). To correct for this, you add 1.

[`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week, which is also 0-indexed starting from Sunday (So 4 is Thursday).

Here, you would use [`Date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) to get the day in the current month (Which is not 0-indexed).

```js
var da = new Date('2016-11-25'),
nda = new Date(da-86400000);
document.write(nda.getFullYear() + "-" +
               (nda.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
                nda.getDate());
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a fundamental rule wiht parsing dates: do not use the Date constructor or Date.parse (they are equivalent for parsing) to parse date strings. Use a library with a parser or parse it yourself with a simple function.

When using:

```
var da = new Date('2016-11-25');
```

the date will be treated as UTC, so if you are in a timezone that is west of Greenwich the local date will be the day before. Note the differences in the following:

```js
console.log('Built-in parse: ' + new Date('2016-11-25').toLocaleString());
console.log('No parse      : ' + new Date(2016, 10, 25).toLocaleString());
```

When you do:

```
nda.getFullYear()+"-"+nda.getMonth()+"-"+nda.getDay();
```

as others have said, you should use `nda.getMonth() + 1`, and you want *getDate* rather than *getDay*. However, since you are parsing the date as UTC then getting local values, the previous issue with UTC may mean that the date is one day previous.

To construct a date in the local time zone and avoid parsing errors, set the values directly.

To get the day before any date, simply subtract one day. Don't subtract 24 hours or you'll then get errors over daylight saving boundaries (since those days aren't exactly 24 hours long). e.g.:

```js
/* Format a date as yyyy-mm-dd
** @param {Date} date
** @returns {string}
*/
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' +
        ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
        ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2); 
}

var nda = new Date(2016, 10, 25);
console.log('Created date: ' + formatDate(nda));

nda.setDate(nda.getDate() - 1);
console.log('Previous day: ' + formatDate(nda));
```